# Register more than one callback function in same hook with different parameters in wordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

How to register(add) **more than one callback function in same hook(like init, wp_footer, wp_head, etc) with different parameters** in **wordPress Plugin**.
Please explain with simple example.

Comment: Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. If you have a specific question, it should include details of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks man for suggesting me.

Comment: *Wo*man :-)  You are more likely to get answers if you can provide clear and relevant information, so its to your own benefit to do some research and include your code here. Have a go and come back with some examples that we can help you with!